# run animation at the same time not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

So, i'm trying to run 2 animation at the same time on mouseover

However, after using `queue:false` they still running one after another :(

here's what i got:

```
        $(document.body).on('mouseover', '.j-ad-slide', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('.j-ad-slide').animate({
                height: '370px'
            }, {
                    duration: 500,
                    queue: false,
                    complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
            });

            $('.side-nav, .sub-menu').animate({
                top: '422'
            }, {
                    duration: 500,
                    queue: false,
                    complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
            });             
        });
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? BTW: `.side-nav` and `.sub-menu` elements are `position:fixed` - I think that's the problem. I'm not sure how to work around that :(

Comment: Can u put a jsfiddle.net sample?

Comment: yes, you are right, the code is working find on jsfiddle.net - however doesn't work on my project branch. erg!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. Here is a [fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/jcedric/s4HQ9/1/).

```
$(document.body).on('mouseover', '.animate', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.animate').animate({
            height: '370px'
        }, {
                duration: 500,
                queue: false,
                complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
        });

        $('.animate2').animate({
            left: '100'
        }, {
                duration: 500,
                queue: false,
                complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
        });             
    });
```

[fiddle with fixed position](http://jsfiddle.net/jcedric/s4HQ9/2/)